# Codificação no C++

Tags: c++

Oi,gostaria de saber como mudar a codificação de output do C++,sabendo que a codificação padrão é o ASCII.

Já tentei com as bibliotecas `<windows.h>` e `<tchar.h>`,no seguinte código:

```
int main(){
    _tsetlocale(LC_ALL, _T("portuguese"));
    (...)
}
```

Mas percebo que além de não funcionar em outros OS,seta apenas para o português.

Pretendo utilizar de vários caracteres,de várias linguagens na aplicação mas não faço ideia de como fazer.

UTF-8 é uma opção?Se sim,como implementar?

Comment: O C++ não tem uma "codificação de output". A sua saída vai ser um stream de bytes e o que importa é que o código que for exibir essa stream esteja preparado para ler o encoding que você usou (naturalmente, isso depende de se vc vai exibir num terminal, numa GUI no windows, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distancie-se das funções "set locale" (como tsetlocale). Elas não têm a ver com o seu problema agora.

E o que nosso colega hugomg disse está certo. A saída do seu programa são bytes (tipo, são números). E como eles serão mostrados na tela de QUALQUER sistema operacional, depende do ambiente de execução do programa. Pra dar um exemplo, imagine um programa simples, que apenas escreve "Oi, mundo!" e termina. Se executarmos esse programa num terminal com codificação diferente do que os BYTES dessa string dentro programa têm, a frase vai aparecer de um jeito maluco. Se estiver certo, dá certo. Só isso.

Então, pesquisa um pouco sobre o seguinte (a Wikipédia é uma professora pra isso). 1) Codificação ASCII. 2) Codificação ISO-8859-1. 3) Codificação UTF-8. Lembrando que UTF-8 não tem mais correspondência de 1 byte por símbolo, como nas outras que citei.

Meus programas em C usam acentos nas strings dos printfs. E isso funciona bem, desde que as strings no código fonte tenham a mesma codificação do terminal/tela onde o programa será executado. Normalmente escolher a codificação comum do sistema alvo já garante isso. ISO-8859-1 e UTF-8 têm sido as melhores escolhas em 90% do casos. E os casos à parte ficam fáceis de mudar, quando precisa. Entende esse parágrafo?

Pra terminar, existe uma função e/ou uma biblioteca e/ou um programa chamados iconv. Com isso você pode converter suas strings de uma codificação para outra desejada. Pode ajudar também.

Resumindo:

1. descubra e escolha a codificação que todas as strings no seu código fonte têm; isso depende do seu editor, é simples.
2. Escolha a codificação que seu programa terá na saída, e isso passará a ser requisito pra quem for usá-lo; o termnal/tela da pessoa entenderá naturalmente as strings do seu programa. UTF-8 ou ISO-8859-1 são ótimas apostas, na minha opinião.
3. Por fim, você pode usar a função iconv() quando for necessário algo mais "detalhado".

Leituras úteis:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1 (em inglês)

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1 (em português, só pro básico; artigo não está tão completo, ainda)

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html (manual da função iconv, em inglês)

http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv

Comment: Vale a pena enfatizar que se uma string estiver usando um encoding multibyte algumas operações como contar o número de caracteres ou extrair uma substring ficam mais complicadas. Se você tiver só passando o buffer de caracteres de um lado pro outro não tem muito problema mas se você quiser manipulá-lo tome cuidado e use uma biblioteca que faça a coisa certa.